# Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

```
Array.Copy(Wh_PhnNum_List, this.Wh_PhnNum_List, Wh_PhnNum_List.Length); This line show a exception below..
```

ERROR : **An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.**

My code is below :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0)]
            public struct st_SOTA_Authen_Config
            {
                char[] Wh_PhnNum_List;

                ushort payload_length;

                //CONSTRUCTOR
                public st_SOTA_Authen_Config (char[] Wh_PhnNum_List)
                {
                    this.Wh_PhnNum_List = new char[CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_PHN_NUM_STR_SZ];

                    Common.InitToZero(ref this.Wh_PhnNum_List);

                    Array.Copy(Wh_PhnNum_List, this.Wh_PhnNum_List, Wh_PhnNum_List.Length);

                    this.payload_length =  CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_WH_PHNNUM_LIST_STR_SZ + (sizeof(byte) *3);
                }
```

why that exception occur ?? How to resolve problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter, named `Wh_PhnNum_List` must be larger than whatever `CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_PHN_NUM_STR_SZ` is set to. You should replace that first line with `this.Wh_PhnNum_List = new char[Wh_PhnNum_List.Length]`.

Comment: Now it Show this Exception :  An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in iWave_Configuration_Tool.exe

Additional information: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.

Comment: Which line is throwing that exception? If it's not the Copy line then you should consider forming a new question. This seems as though you are now trying to access indices in an array which do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Method to Convert the Structure to byte array
            public byte[] ToByteArray()
            {
                byte[] b = new byte[LENGTH];

                byte[] Wh_PhnNum_List = new byte[CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_WH_PHNNUM_LIST_STR_SZ];

                Wh_PhnNum_List = Common.CharArrayToByteArray(this.Wh_PhnNum_List);

                Buffer.BlockCopy(Wh_PhnNum_List, 0, b, 0, CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_WH_PHNNUM_LIST_STR_SZ);
                return b;
            }
```

It Shows below Exception   for this line

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(Wh_PhnNum_List, 0, b, 0, CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_WH_PHNNUM_LIST_STR_SZ);
```